# How to Write a Dot in Subscript?

Tags: formatting, subscripts

I'm trying to write a dot over a subscript - like

```
    f_{\dot{x}}
```

My problem is that this comes out looking all wrong. The dot is inside the x, it's just messy. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

P.S I'm doing this because I want to write the euler-lagrange equations in the more compact form

```
    f_{x}=\dot{f_{\dot{x}}}
```

so I need a method that will accompany another dot on top of the one in the subscript. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Mico answered this below to all who have the same issue! Thanks Mico!

Comment: You can do `f^{}_{\dot{x}}`, with a dummy superscript. It's unclear what you want to achieve with `f_{x}=\dot{f_{\dot{x}}}`: can you show an approximate representation or point to some image?

Comment: Do you load the `amsmath` package? Please confirm.

Comment: Thank you all! Mico answered with exactly what I needed below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change from `\dot{f_{\dot{x}}}` to `\dot{f}_{\dot{x}}`, both dots will be placed correctly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$f_{x}=\dot{f}_{\dot{x}}$
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: A second MWE, which shows the OP's formula, the improvement suggested above, and a possible further improvement on.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
bad & good & best(?) \\[1ex]
$\dot{f_{\dot{x}}}$ & $\dot{f}_{\dot{x}}$ & $\dot{f}^{}_{\!\dot{x}}$ 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Damn you've beaten me by a split second! :)

Comment: very good for your work +1.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. Much obliged to all who commented!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something clunky like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\mydot}[1]{\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\scriptsize$\dot{#1}$}}

\begin{document}
\[
f_{\dot x}  \quad f_{\mydot{x}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]